# Valid way of evaluating limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculate the following limits $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\sin x} - \sin^2x -1}{x},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x \cos x - x}{x^2 e^x}.$$

I've evaluated these using the asymptotic equivalences $$\sin x \sim_0 x, \, \,\,\,\cos x \sim_0 1$$ as follows:

$$\frac{e^{\sin x} - \sin^2x -1}{x} \sim_0 \frac{e^x - x^2 -1}{x} = \frac{e^x -1}{x} - x \to 1$$
and
$$\frac{\sin x \cos x - x}{x^2 e^x} \sim_0 \frac{x-x}{x^2 e^x} = 0.$$

Are my calculations correct?

Comment: You can use L-Hopital

Comment: I know, but I was wondering if this way is correct as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say asymptotic in this case. I would call it approximation (up to certain error). For example
$$\sin x = x +O(x^3),...$$
Your explanations are not correct (although incidently the results are correct). To see why it is wrong, try to the argument in the second case for $x^{2014}e^x$ instead of $x^2e^x$ in the denominator.

Comment: Ok got it. However, I still don't fully understand why I can't use these approximations in this case?

Comment: Approximations have errors. When you do $\sin x\cos x\sim_0 x$, you encounter an error comparable to $x^3$, which is smaller than the denominator ($x^2e^x$), hence the correct answer. However, since you choose to ignore the error, the argument is not mathematically correct.

Comment: Ahh yeah, that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

I think things will be more explicit if we rewrite the given expression as

$$\frac{e^{\sin x}-1}{\sin x}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)-\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)\sin x$$